# How to set dynamically values to array using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using multiple text box with different name . i want to set values to an array in a collection of list for example room name, room desc, extra bed . these inputs will be dynamically loaded . i have collect all the details and have to set in one array list.

my array collection

```
var Roominfo;
Roominfo.ROOMNAME;
Roominfo.ROOMDESC;
Roominfo.ROOMTYPEID;
Roominfo.BEDTYPE;
Roominfo.EXTRABED;
Roominfo.MAXADULT;
Roominfo.MAXKIDS;
Roominfo.ROOMSTATUS;
Roominfo = [];
```

how get values from those input text box to set in these type of array using jquery . please help me

my jquery for set input val to particular value

```
 var roomname = $("input[name='RoomName']");
            $.each(roomname, function (i, item) {  //i=index, item=element in array
                var i=0;
                if ($(item).val() == '')
                {
                    norooms = 1;
                    roomnames = [];
                    $(this).addClass('dtTxtError');
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                else
                {
                    norooms = 1;


                    Roominfo.ROOMNAME.push($(item).val());
                   // roomnames.ROOMNAME.push($(item).val());
                    console.log(Roominfo);
                }
            });
```

in that i am get push can not find

```
 Roominfo.ROOMNAME.push($(item).val());
```

Comment: Please provide more code, including your HTML input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `object` to save Roominfo, like this:

```
var Roominfo = {
    ROOMNAME: []
};
```

So you can use `push()` now

```
 Roominfo['ROOMNAME'].push($(item).val());
```